# EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection. - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, server-sent-events

I am getting an error while implementing SSE.

Error :
`EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection. - Codeigniter`

Below you can find the code :

```
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {   
    var path = "<?php echo base_url()?>lawyer/consultation/video_calling/<?php echo $client_user_id ?>";
    var source = new EventSource(path);
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var img_url     = '<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/images/main-logo.png';
        var resp        = JSON.parse(event.data);
        var id          = resp.id;
        var sender_id   = resp.sender_id;
        var receiver_id = resp.receiver_id;
        var session_id  = resp.session_id;
        var token       = resp.token;
        var client_receiver_id = <?php echo $client_user_id ?>;

        if(client_receiver_id == receiver_id){ 
            // alert('fgdgdg');
            spawnNotification('Somebody calling you!', ''+img_url+'', 'LawOn says');
            //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
        }
    };
} else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "SSE not Supported";
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Explain what your intention is with the code and what you want to happen.

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement SSE in codeigniter.I am getting the above error - I am unable to establish the connection.I don't know where is the problem.I am stuck.Is there any problem with the header i am passing??

Comment: Maybe this will help, as it shows setting the headers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44495797/841830